# JavaFX Grouping and Removing Nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a code that creates an application that draws dots at whichever point I click. I'm new to JavaFX and I understand the general principle on how to add objects to the screen and everything works except I cannot figure out how to remove items. I am currently looking through a LinkedList and if the dot with the same coordinates exists i'm using pane.getChildren().remove(index), this is assuming that the only indices in the pane are my dot objects and they correspond with my linked list indices. Also maybe creating a group would help with this project? I don't really understand the purpose of a group, and when I tried to replace the code with a group object instead of a pane object the dots stopped appearing.

Here is the code i'm trying to figure out, i'll add comments to help

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Dots!");
    // TODO: Your code starts here
    currentColor = Color.RED;
    dotList = new SinglyLinkedList<Dot>();
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setPrefSize(SIZE, SIZE);
    Dot dot = new Dot(50 ,50);
    dot.setFill(currentColor);
    //dotList.add(dot);
    //pane.getChildren().add(dot);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    stage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage

    pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {          
        switch (e.getCode()) {
          case DIGIT1: currentColor = Color.RED; break;
          case DIGIT2:  currentColor = Color.BLUE; break;
          case DIGIT3: currentColor = Color.GREEN; break;
          case NUMPAD1: currentColor = Color.RED; break;
          case NUMPAD2:  currentColor = Color.BLUE; break;
          case NUMPAD3: currentColor = Color.GREEN; break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      });
      pane.requestFocus(); 

      pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
          double x = e.getX();
          double y = e.getY();
          int index = 0;
          int size = dotList.size();
          if (size !=0 && index < size) {
              Dot check = dotList.get(index);
              if (check.contains(x, y)) { 
                  dotList.remove(index);
                  pane.getChildren().remove(index); //This is may be wrong
                  size = dotList.size();
              }
              index++;
          }
          Dot newDot = new Dot(x ,y);
          dotList.add(newDot);
          pane.getChildren().add(newDot); ///This adds a new dot, this works


      });
      pane.requestFocus(); 

    // Your code ends here

    stage.show(); // makes the window visible to the user
}
```

Comment: Could I made a group of dots and set the scene as the group or something? I understand that the group can hold all my dot objects, but I don't understand how to set the scene to look at the objects in the group

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to complete my iteration when I made the code so it was only hitting index of 0